# Why is rails query caching not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, query-cache

In my development environment I have a single request that is generating hundreds of the same queries:

```
Person Load (24.4ms)  SELECT "persons".* FROM "persons" WHERE ("persons"."person_id" = 517) LIMIT 1  
. . .   
Person Load (64.4ms)  SELECT "persons".* FROM "persons" WHERE ("persons"."person_id" = 517) LIMIT 1
```

Why is this?  I thought Rails was supposed to enable Query caching by default on a per request basis?

```
config/development.rb:  
config.cache_classes = false  
config.perform_caching = true    
. . .    
# Show full error reports and disable caching  
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true  
config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true  
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true  
config.active_support.deprecation        = :log
```

Comment: Are the queries cached in the production environment?

Answer (score 5):

If you're connecting to multiple databases (say by using establish_connection in certain models), it appears that only the ActiveRecord::Base.connection gets query caching enabled. Not sure if that's the case here, but certainly a tricky side effect of connecting to multiple DBs.

Comment: Just to add to that, the way around this seems to be to manually use YourRecord.cache { } around the code you want cached. Keep in mind that the cache will be wiped at the end of the block, so make sure any repeating queries you want cached run before the block exits.

Comment: @MattZukowski, do you consider that is rails bug or not?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using passenger and memcache in production?

http://www.russbrooks.com/2010/10/20/rails-cache-memcache-on-passenger-with-smart-spawning